# iframe scaling width issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

I am using a zoom /scaling to resize an iframe:

```
{
-ms-zoom: 0.80;
-moz-transform: scale(0.80);
-o-transform: scale(0.80);
-webkit-transform: scale(0.80);
-o-transform-origin: 0 0;
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

This works well for what I want, however where the width is resized it leaves margins where 100% stays as -20%. I could theoretically detect the width of the parent and then use jQuery after the resize to set it, or maybe zoom the inside page instead, but I am hoping someone can give me a more elegant solution that does'nt involve using jquery for styling?

http://jsfiddle.net/ablueman/8uvz0fzf/

[edit]
Similiar issue: [Scrolling when using css scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26730890/scrolling-when-using-css-scale/26731534#26731534)

Comment: Is this question lacking clarity? can anyone add anything or is the only answer to use jquery / javascript?

Comment: Hey there, I don't quite get what effect you are trying to achieve. Could you be a little more clear?

Comment: Hey Frederik thanks for looking: essentially with or without zoom. #testiframe width and height should = #iframediv. But when you zoom. It doesnt just scale the contents, it scales the element leaving whitespace / greyspace.

Comment: and as per my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26730890/scrolling-when-using-css-scale/26731534#26731534 I cant just make things 120% it would then not be the same value/size as the original size.

Comment: Why do you need the iframediv? When it should be the same size as the iframe, it is pretty useless, right?

Comment: Or did u mean this? http://jsfiddle.net/8uvz0fzf/66/

Comment: Its mainly for demonstration purposes and the wider project. http://jsfiddle.net/ablueman/8uvz0fzf/67/ #wrap is the parent element. This sets size. #iframediv demonstrates the height/width it SHOULD be. (and is what im using jquery to target size on in an attempt to fix it). the iframe itself is the problem though as its 100% width is becoming 80% (or whatever) in comparison to iframediv which of course remains as 100%.

Comment: Ah I got you. This is because you just scale it to 0.9, not to 1.0. Wait a second

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8uvz0fzf/68/

Comment: heh, well I'm grateful that you managed to get the slider to work with scale 1. I didnt know how to do that either. But thats not the fix. The fix would mean the IFRAME stays the same SIZE as #wrap. But zooms the content only. This may mean I have to dynamically resize the iframe width/height to counter balance the -20% or -30%. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think you are mistaken something. The whitespace in the iframe itself, comes from the page you are linking. The image in the iframe is not the full width the body. That is why you have a little whitespace in your iframe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64234/discussion-between-ablueman-and-frederik-witte).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As via css it is only possible to affect the iframe itself, not the iframe contents (eg `iframe body`), you can't do this with css. That being said, you can access the contents of an iframe via javascript. With jQuery it would be something like:

```
$('iframe').contents().find(body).css('zoom', yourvalue);
```

Comment: Finally got round to making a test version up that targets the contents of the iframe rather than the iframe and it has the desired effect.

Comment: Bit of a bodge job at the moment, however let me edit the answer then you can vote it up if you find it useful .. give me a short while as im at im at work  ..

Comment: Done. New answer as this isnt mine

Answer (score 2):

So heres what I did to bodge a working version, I will either link this to a slider so you can zoom in and out (using var bob) or perhaps make it dynamic with a responsive iframe but heres what I have so far:

```
<script>
function mainiframe(){
var bob = "0.90";
$('iframe#mainiframe, iframe#injectIframe').contents().find('body').css({
            "margin" : 0,
      "zoom": bob,
            "-moz-transform": "scale(" + bob + ")",
            "-webkit-transform": "scale(" + bob + ")",
            "-o-transform": "scale(" + bob + ")",
            "-o-transform-origin": "0 0",
            "-moz-transform-origin": "0 0",
            "-webkit-transform-origin": "0 0"
    });
};
</script>
```

Then in the body of the document.

```
<button onclick="mainiframe()">Click me</button>
```

Obviously this wont work cross domain, and as you can see I actually zoom out 2 iframes at once.
If I can link this to the responsive Iframe with some kind of ratio I may be able to make a responsive iframe with zoom, but the problems complicated.

Doesnt work perfectly due to JSfiddles page setup but : http://jsfiddle.net/ablueman/w4e8zu52/

[Edit] New bodge with slider: http://jsfiddle.net/ablueman/8uvz0fzf/
It only affects:

> "Error 404  We're truly sorry, but there is no such page."

But shows working, obviously this wouldnt be an issue with a normal iframe page.