# Scrolling when using css scale

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with css and I have to admit that I am just learning it.

I have a header that stays at the top and a "content" area that should be scrollable.

Here are the two css classes:

```
body,
        div {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body {
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #header {
            overflow: auto;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: #DEE7F2;
            border-width: 2px;
            border-bottom-width:2px;
            border-bottom-color:Black;
            border-bottom-style: solid;
        }

        #main {
            overflow: auto;
            position: absolute;                
            top: 200px;
            width: 100%;
            bottom: 0;                
        }

<body>
    <div id="header">
        some stuff here
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        a lot of stuff here
    </div>
<body>
```

This works fine though. Now I added a drop down to select the scale of the "content area" because the content will be quite large.

This is the CSS class that I add to the main div to have the scale of 10%:

```
.scale10 {
            -ms-transform: scale(0.1);
            -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
            -o-transform: scale(0.1);
            -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
            transform: scale(0.1);
            -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
            -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
            -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
            -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
            transform-origin: 0 0;
        }
```

This is how the page look like in 100% scale (without the additional class)

[image: This is the 100% scale page]

As you can see the page is scaled but is not using the whole width of the screen. Also, the scrollbars do not use the whole width... I want the main page to use the full width thats why I used the "width: 100%" statement in the main class. I tried to remove the statement but then the scrollbars are missing...

[image: This is the 10% scale image]

What I want is to scale the main-div but leave the width at 100% so that the image uses the whole screen. Also I want scrollbars because the content will still be larger then the screen - even with a scale of 10%.

Can some CSS god help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do your effect:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1nx0fm1d/)

You simply have to wrap your content in another container, and you place this container in your main area. Then you scale not your main area, but just your content.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
}

.content:hover {
  width: 120%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Added a hover state just for demonstration.

Comment: No Problem, if you need more help, feel free to ask.